# Accessing IPython command line from node.js and websockets

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How would I go about creating a web app using node.js (Express.js) that can access the python or ipython REPL command line? Essentially I would like to have something like the [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html), but integrated into a node.js web application. I was also thinking about using websockets for low-latency, two-way communication between the app and the python instance on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use ZMQ node binding, and talk directly to the kernel using [same protocol than IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html), if you want IPython notebook for node you can create a [node kernle](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4279371/node-kernel.ipynb) (need to be updated for last protocol version). IPython webserver already have websocket and Emacs [EIN](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/) alredy use it to speek to server through websocket.

[Edit]

Some clarification after comments.
About the notebook, at first order when you open the notebook web app 3 component are involved.

- The Kernel (K) -- IPython kernel in our case, but can be IJulia, IHaskell...
- The Server (S) -- Tornado in our case
- The Client (C) -- Html/Js frontend for notebook

(K) talk to (S) using ZMQ.
(S) act as a bridge that doe ZMQ<->Websocket translation
(C) Talk to S through websocket.

What goes on the wire on ZMQ and Websocket is language agnostic, so you don't **care** of the language of (K), (S) or (C). ZMQ and Websocket have a high change of **not** using the same transport, **not** using the same interface/ip, and **not** using the same port.

Comment: I haven't been able to find documentation on how to programmatically access the IPython web notebook so I can embed it within my own application though. Is there anything available?

Comment: I'm not sure there are lots of doc around for websocket. I would have a look at `kernel.js`, [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5632595) and probably [this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/development/messaging.html) the websocket/zmq bridge makes only minimal changes (if any) to the messages.

Comment: By the way, we are trying to make our JS modular. We would **love** to be able to have a kernel.js file that could be a separate module and used as-is on both node.js and in browser. We are not javascript developpers and any help is always really appreciated. Don't hesitate to open issue/PR on github.

Comment: So I finally got around to trying to implement this (getting node to talk to IPython) from [your example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4279371/node-kernel.ipynb). I am having some issues with the zeromq ports. The three ports in `kernel.js` should match up with `c.IPKernelApp.hb_port`,  `c.IPKernelApp.ipub_port`, and `c.IPKernelApp.shell_port` right? I added these to my `node` profile, yet I am still getting random ports when I connect with my notebook, e.g. `[NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:57405`. Any suggestions on what I'm missing here to get your example working?

Comment: No, `c.IPKernelApp.hb_port` `...` are ZMQ port, `kernel.js` connect to tornado that make the ZMQ-websoket bridge. Hence the port (and the protocol) are different. Stack-Overflow might be a little small to explain that. Is your project public, or otherwise bring the question on IPython-dev(at)scipy.org

Comment: Ah, so which ports should be in the config file for node? I'll go ahead and send a note to the mailing list as well.

Comment: A bit more: My understanding is that websockets are the glue between tornado and notebook, and zmq is the glue between tornado and ipython. For my case, websockets is the glue between my web app and node.js. Hopefully I can use the node-kernel.js example you showed as the glue to allow node.js to marshall commands to ipython as well. I'm unclear though how to actually figure out which zmq sockets/ports are the ones to pass to node.js so the same ipython instance can be used on the backend.

Comment: Ahhhhh ! 2 things. First there are 2 `kernel.js`, the one of the web-app, and the one in my gist. 2) With all the question I answer to I'm starting to mix things. So Forget what I said. Your problem is that `ipython notebook`can spawn many kernels, hence `c.IPKernelApp.hb_port` will not work. You can spawn an unique kernel with `ipython kernel` that will respect the config, or even better, not set the the port at all, let it choose and read from the connexion file it emits.

Comment: This makes sense... however, I am running into this error now: `ImportError: No module named zmq.subprocesskernel
` (http://pastebin.com/dTzmmTF6). IPython does not seem to contain this module anymore, was it possibly renamed in a refactoring?

Comment: Probably, at the time I wrote that IPython had to be patched, it is not the case anymore. But you should'nt need to change the kernel launcher class in your case as you want to talk to python kernels. It would be easier to help you If I could see part if the code.,,

Comment: I set up a basic example of starting Notebook, then reading the config settings into node and trying to connect with the heart beats. Here is a gist of the code and the error message I get: https://gist.github.com/stanley-gu/7237081

Comment: Ah, so I don't get the error if I use `node kernel` instead of notebook, which is okay for now. I don't seem to be seeing any heartbeats though. How would I send a simple 'hello world' message to IPython from node? I'll update the gist to show you what I'm trying.